# How much and what to automate in this project

Tags: selenium-webdriver

The AUT is a web application. There are different types of users like admint, consumer etc.

The application is a utility domain application. There is hardly any data that user/human inputs into the system.

The data is coming from electronic meters and getting stored in the database. 
Our application only renders the data to the consumers, admins and other users with the data with different calculations in the form of charts and graphs.

There are about 9-10 pages in the application.

My question is : How can I proceed with automation in this scenario..?

Comment: Firstly save the data which was entered by the user and execute them using selenium webdriver by retrieving the same data.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow is a Q&A programming site and while your question seems like it would be a good fit for the site, it isn't. It's more of an opinion-based question rather than a specific programming question and as such is likely to get closed soon. I would suggest that you ask this question on the SO sister site, sqa.stackexchange.com. Good luck!

Comment: Its OK if there are opinion. Not all opinions will be wrong and will be upto the person wanting the answer to choose the appropriate one.